# Whose side is Ymir in?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I'm watching Attack on Titan episode 10 season 2. Whose side is Ymir in? First,

> she was along the others fighting mindless Titan. Later, she was captured by Bertolt and Reiner and she was against them. Later, she's cooperating with them and she talks with them about bringing Christa with them. She seems like she is neither on one side nor the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tbh, its not much of a question. If you want spoilers, read the wiki/Manga. The question will eventually be answered in the Anime.

**The best answer I can give is She is on her own side**. She decided to accept Reiner's proposal which is deemed to be mutually beneficial. Some context below

> Ymir was a mindless Titan who ate Reiner, Bertholt and Annie's companion, who like them had shifter powers. This is also the reason why Titans eat humans. To consume the spinal fluid from a Shifter so they are no longer Titans. 
>  Ymir Henceforth gained the Shifter powers. She is attached to Historia and thus saved her life, however decided to accompany Reiner to gain more knowledge and details.

Comment: This is something I dont like about movies/animes, etc. nowadays. If you dont read extra material, such as comics/manga, videogames, etc. you don't understand a lot of things which are going on. And about getting all the answers in the same media, that doesnt always happen

Comment: @Pablo Its an anime based on manga. So obviously it would lag behind. The second season is mid way, so you can exoect more answers by season end.